# Hibernate doesn't load UUID value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate 5.2.12 and MySQL 5.7.18.

Have following entity in my project:

```
package my.package;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import pl.chilldev.commons.db.AbstractEntity;
import pl.chilldev.commons.db.timestampable.Timestamp;
import pl.chilldev.commons.db.timestampable.TimestampType;
import pl.chilldev.commons.db.timestampable.TimestampableListener;

/**
* Recording meta entity.
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "Recordings")
@EntityListeners(TimestampableListener.class)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
public class Recording extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
    * Assigned shop.
    */
    @Column(length = AbstractEntity.LENGTH_UUID, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Setter
    private UUID idShop;

    /**
    * Track title.
    */
    @Column(length = AbstractEntity.LENGTH_STRING_COMPACT, nullable = false)
    @Setter
    private String name;

    /**
    * Track description.
    */
    @Column
    @Type(type = "text")
    @Setter
    private String content;

    /**
    * Creation date.
    */
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Timestamp(TimestampType.CREATE)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    /**
    * Track price.
    */
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Setter
    private double price;

    /**
    * Thumbnail S3 key.
    */
    @Column(length = AbstractEntity.LENGTH_URL)
    @Setter
    private String thumbnail;

    /**
    * Media file S3 key.
    */
    @Column(length = AbstractEntity.LENGTH_URL)
    @Setter
    private String media;

    /**
    * Length of recording.
    */
    @Column
    @Setter
    private Short duration;

    /**
    * Categories to which recording is assigned.
    */
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "RecordingsCategories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idRecording"))
    @Column(name = "idCategory", length = AbstractEntity.LENGTH_UUID, nullable = false)
    private List<UUID> categories;
}
```

(AbstractEntity defines just one `id` attribute of type UUID.)

When I save entity (I use Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST, so I just invoke endpoint) everything works fine.

But for whatever reason Hibernate doesn't want to load `idShop` property back from database. When I access some endpoint that loads the entity, `idShop` is always null. I've tried to nail it down and seems to be within Hibernate (not related to Spring, Spring Data etc.).

Here is a printout from MySQL console:

```
mysql> select *, hex(idShop) from Recordings;
+------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------+-------+------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| id               | content | createdAt           | duration | idShop           | media | name | price | thumbnail | hex(idShop)                      |
+------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------+-------+------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| �HG_OƵ�㰅aY     | NULL    | 2018-04-04 23:36:46 |     NULL | �߈'��C�����9K�           | NULL  | Test |     2 | NULL      | A6DF8827B2F043B4BBE7DADA394B11D2 |
+------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------+-------+------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

During the debugging the value of idShop property is loaded prperly, but some `wasNull` property of result set evaluates to `true` and causes entire evaluation to also become null:

[image]

## EDIT 1

Table (created by Hibernate itself):

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE Recordings;
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Recordings | CREATE TABLE `Recordings` (
`id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
`content` longtext,
`createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
`duration` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`idShop` binary(16) NOT NULL,
`media` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`price` double NOT NULL,
`thumbnail` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Just to make it even more weird - `List<UUID> categories` is being loaded properly.

Comment: Can you also post the output off `SHOW CREATE TABLE Recordings`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Added to the post.

Comment: have a feeling you to need have these annotations `@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")` for the idShop variable..

Comment: `idShop` is not a primary key, this is just a UUID identifier I put there manually. It's specified in the data. It IS SAVED in the table (see the printout and even debugging window - the value is there). The problem is that for whatever reason Hibernate (or MySQL driver?) sets null flag.